# How to choose the appearance of the Gmail app?

Tags: gmail, google-apps

In Android, Gmail released an [update](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-6730409/Gmails-bright-white-redesign-Android-users-use-Googles-revamped-email-app.html), and it asked me for Default, Comfortable or Compact appearance.

I chose the Default, ofc I don't like it, I miss the old red bar already..

Now I want to try the Comfortable appearance in the Gmail application. How to?

Comment: FYI, the Default, Comfortable or Compact choices refer solely to the density of the messages grid/rows, not the overall appearance/color scheme of the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the Android App, click the 3 horizontal bars (top left) -> scroll down to Settings -> General Settings (the top option) -> Conversation List Density (Default / Comfortable / Compact.)

It took me forever to finally find this setting! It was driving me crazy.

Comment: Extra level of difficulty — in another language this setting might _not mention density at all_. In Russian it says something like "mode of conversation chain". That makes sense...

Answer (score 2):

Click the gear icon in the top right corner, select "display density," then select your choice. By the way, I think "compact" is the most space efficient and most like the original gmail display.

Comment: Hey Maggie, welcome to the site, and thanks for the answer! What you say works in a desktop computer.. I am asking about the Gmail app, I will edit my question, and +1 to you, since future readers might benefit from your answer.